# Multidimensional JavaScript Array to PHP Array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile. I have a multidimensional array in JavaScript that is 12 columns wide and an unknown number of rows like so

```
/*
[
    [userID (int), name, username, email, password, other 1, other 2, other 3, other 4, other 5, other 6, admin(int)],
    [userID (int), name, username, email, password, other 1, other 2, other 3, other 4, other 5, other 6, admin(int)],
    [userID (int), name, username, email, password, other 1, other 2, other 3, other 4, other 5, other 6, admin(int)],
    ...
]
*/
```

All the values are string except the (int) ones. This is for a real time user editing page for my site. I have the JavaScript array made now I need it so when the "Submit" button is pressed it turns the array formated like that into an PHP array and saves it as a variable. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 6):

[Encode to JSON](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php), [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) to PHP via [Ajax](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) or [regular Form](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input) and decode on the serverside with [json_decode](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: That was the most odd comment I've seen on SO

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add the data to hidden fields in your form, if they are not already regular input fields.

You probably want to use field naming like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[100][username]" value="myusername" />
<input type="hidden" name="data[100][email]" value="name@example.com" />
```

Where `100` is whatever each user id is.

Comment: It has a new user function and can be edited live. I do not see how that would work with that.